# Shopify SKU not updating when variant is selected

Tags: shopify, liquid, sku

I'm calling in a product SKU number that is supposed to change when the variant is selected based on [this Shopify tutorial](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/show-sku-numbers).

As instructed I place the following snippet where I want the SKU to display:

```
{% assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
<span class="variant-sku">{{ current_variant.sku }}</span>
```

However, when the variant is changed the SKU never updates like it does in their tutorial's gif.

Here's [an example](https://mostergo.com/products/ergocentric-aircentric-chair) of it on the website where it isn't working.

[image]

Also, here's a screenshot showing that the option is indeed a Shopify variant and not something else (just so all my bases are covered).

My only guess is that Shopify may have changed and this is done differently now or that I've somehow set something up incorrectly, though I've followed the tutorial's instructions (placed inside the product-template.liquid, which is referenced from the product.liquid (the theme is sectioned).

[image]

Comment: Can you share your store url? which theme you are using? I can hep you to fix it...

Comment: Yes definitely, the URL is actually above where it says 'an example' (https://mostergo.com/products/ergocentric-aircentric-chair). I'm using the Debut theme too (most recent version I believe).

Comment: See here I have added some code to change the sku

https://channelpilot.myshopify.com/collections/frontpage/products/t-short-short-sleeve-28

password:- rtublu

Let me know if that works well for you or not..

Comment: did you checked it?

Comment: Sorry @YuvrajJain I haven't - it asks for a email address - what email address should I put in?

Comment: there is a button on the top left "Enter Using Password" when you cilck it you can put "rtublu" as password and can see it....

Comment: Is this the Debut theme? It doesn't use option selection but there will be something similar to the selectCallback function that you will need to modify to get this working.

Comment: @ButsAndCats Yes it is the Debut theme. Sounds like there is a different way to make this happen for that theme - have any references or sample code?

Comment: @jhawes Yes. Take a look at the `slate.Variants` function in the theme.js. Specifically `_onChangeSelect` which is fired when a variant is changed and `this._updatePrice(variant);`

Comment: @ButsAndCats I am finding the slate.Variants section you referred, but I'm not finding the '_onChangeSelect' unfortunately. I'm curious if my problem might be caused by a plugin - one is installed that controls extra variants, though these variants are added by the plugin, which is why I dismissed that as a possibility at first.

Comment: @jhawes What kind of plugin? Or do you mean an app? try checking out line 523 of the theme.js

Comment: @ButsAndCats sorry, app is correct (the app is BOLD Product Options). In the theme.js file I did try adding `this._updateSku(variant);` - doesn't appear to do anything though. Placed right below the `this._updatePrice(variant);` line.

Comment: Ahh yeh, bold apps are junk.

Comment: Bummer, so you think the app might be causing a conflict too? Either way I've reached out to them and will confirm on here if that was indeed the problem in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never edited the Assets/theme.js file for this website and I'm fairly certain no one else touched any of the files except for myself.

Despite that there was a very important function left out of the theme.js file that is needed for the variant to change the sku.

**These were the lines that seemed to have not been installed in my theme.js file:**

```
_updateSKU: function(variant) {
  if (variant.sku === this.currentVariant.sku) {
    return;
  }

  this.$container.trigger({
    type: 'variantSKUChange',
    variant: variant
  });
},
```

Also, for the `_initVarients` function the following was missing (place with the other lines that have the same type of code):

```
this.$container.on('variantSKUChange' + this.settings.namespace, this._updateSKU.bind(this));
```

**These were not missing in my theme.js file, though worth checking as they are necessary for the SKU to update:**

Located inside the `_onSelectChange` function (place with the other lines that have the same type of code):

```
this._updateSKU(variant);
```

Located after the `_updatePrice` function:

```
_updateSKU: function(evt) {
      var variant = evt.variant;

      // Update the sku
      $('.variant-sku').html(variant.sku);
    },
```

Comment: Glad you found it :)

Answer (score 0):

I just recently started using Shopify but I'll try to help.  I did notice that you're using `current_variant.sku` but Shopify's object reference material says to use `variant.sku`.  This is where I found it:

https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/variant#variant-sku

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I'm guessing that part of the tutorial might be outdated or designed for non-sectioned themes (newer ones are sectioned). I did try variant.sku anyway though, but no luck. Here's the tutorial I was working off of in case it helps: https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/show-sku-numbers

Comment: I tried it in my code and it works perfectly.  I looked at as much of your code as I could see in devtools, and it looks like the code for the sku isn't inside the form. You should see something below the sku code that says `<form action="/cart/add" method="post" ...>  Stuff is here. div classes and things like that.  Sku code should be here, wherever it looks good to you. </form>`  You need to put the sku code inside those form tags.

Comment: When I first read your comment I thought "hot dang, that's gotta be it... it would make sense to need to be inside the <form>" but still no luck. I updated the page with the SKU calling inside the <form>. https://mostergo.com/collections/office-chairs/products/ergocentric-aircentric-chair?variant=33593402564

Answer (score 0):

```html
  // Variant is sold out, disable the submit button
            // $addToCart.addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
            $addToCart.hide();
            $variantQuantity.removeClass('is-visible');
            if (variant.incoming) {
              $variantQuantity.html({{ 'products.product.will_be_in_stock_after' | t: date: '[date]' | json }}.replace('[date]', variant.next_incoming_date)).addClass('is-visible');
            }
            else {
              $variantQuantity.removeClass('is-visible');
            }
            $quantityElements.hide();
            $outofstock.show();
          }
          //console.log(variant.sku);
          $('.variant-sku').html("");
          $('.variant-sku').text(variant.sku);
           // Update price display.
          var customPrice = Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, theme.moneyFormat);
          if (variant.compare_at_price > variant.price) {
            var comparePrice = Shopify.formatMoney(variant.compare_at_price, theme.moneyFormat);
            var customPriceFormat = ' <del id="old-product-price">' + comparePrice + '</del>';
                customPriceFormat += ' <ins id="product-price">' + customPrice + '</ins>';
            $productPrice.html(customPriceFormat);
            var save = ((variant.compare_at_price - variant.price)*100)/variant.compare_at_price;
            $('#product-{{product.id}} .product-image-summary .onsale').html({{ 'products.product.save_js' | t: saved_amount: '[sale]' | json }}.replace('[sale]', Math.ceil(save))).show();
          }else{
             $productPrice.html(customPrice);
            $('#product-{{product.id}} .product-image-summary .onsale').hide();
          }
          jQuery('.currency .active').trigger('click');
          //Update sku
          if(variant.sku){
             $productsku.text(variant.sku);
            
          }else{
              $productsku.text(theme.strings.na);
            
           }
```

I found that the produc_js.liquid snippet needed to be updated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpARZ.png)